# How can I cap internet for users on virgin

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

I share a house with friends and one of them is very selfish, constantly downloading, streaming music and playing computer games at the same time. How can i cap his devices so the rest of us can use it for normal use?

Extra Details
We use a Netgear Router
On Virgin Broadband

P.S
I have fair knowledge on Computers and programming but not with networks and server, I am happy to learn how to do this just want a pointer as I am lost when looking on google.

Comment: You have to look if your router supports this. If it does not, you have no chance without using something else as router. You have to look for words like "Traffic Shaping", "Quality of Service", "QoS", "Bandwidth limit"

Answer (score 1):

Without installing any additional hardware or software, you should be able to enable a feature called Quality of Service (Sometimes identified by QoS). This prioritizes traffic based on the source so that other devices will still be able to function.

This doesn't actually cap the internet usage for those users, but when you try and use the internet your traffic will get prioritized so that you will not notice the bandwidth usage by the other devices.

For example, this will help with latency sensitive applications such as VoIP where the downloading and streaming will cause the latency to shoot up and make the call quality drop. With QoS enabled, you will see about the same call quality regardless of the downloading and streaming, where the other users will see slightly less performance, but if their main utilization is downloading and streaming the latency will not be as noticeable. And if they complain that it's still not good, tell them to stop downloading or streaming and to try it again, and they'll see how they're impacting the network!

Answer (score 0):

pfSense, firewall, traffic shaping, limiters, away you go.

Just need a box to run it on, but it does not take much of a box, and it will out-route a netgear 10 days out of 10, IME.

See two of my posts at the pfSense forum for the setup (not really any different on the current version.)

https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=101774.msg569030#msg569030
https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=99529.msg555886#msg555886